# XML::Twig newbie script

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I begin to study XML parsing with XML::Twig and I'm involved in 2 little problems.
my xml (a collection of bibliographic records)  has the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<collection xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
 <!-- FIRST INCREMENTAL -->
 <!-- INSTANCE:sfxudn -->
 <record>
  <leader>-----nas-a2200000z--4500</leader>
  <controlfield tag="008">140922uuuuuuuuuxx-uu-|------u|----|eng-d</controlfield>
  <datafield tag="010" ind1="" ind2="">
   <subfield code="a">01015589</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield tag="245" ind1="" ind2="0">
   <subfield code="a">Publishers weekly</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield tag="260" ind1="" ind2="">
   <subfield code="a">New York, NY</subfield>
   <subfield code="b">Reed Business Information</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield tag="022" ind1="" ind2="">
   <subfield code="a">0000-0019</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield tag="776" ind1="" ind2="">
   <subfield code="x">2150-4008</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield tag="090" ind1="" ind2="">
   <subfield code="a">954921332001</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield tag="866" ind1="" ind2="">
   <subfield code="a">Available from 1997. </subfield>
   <subfield code="s">1000000000001224</subfield>
   <subfield code="t">1000000000000630</subfield>
   <subfield code="x">EBSCOhost Business Source Complete:Full Text</subfield>
   <subfield code="z">1000000000125212</subfield>
  </datafield>
 </record>

 ....more records...
  </collection>
```

and I'd like to make 2 manipulations:

1) adding a single costant line (with costant content) in a precise position  in "/collection/record/datafield[\@tag='866']/subfield[\@code='a']".
  in one word, I.E.,  the

```
<datafield tag="866" ind1="" ind2="">
   <subfield code="a">Available from 1997. </subfield>
   <subfield code="s">1000000000001224</subfield>
   <subfield code="t">1000000000000630</subfield>
   <subfield code="x">EBSCOhost Business Source Complete:Full Text</subfield>
   <subfield code="z">1000000000125212</subfield>
  </datafield>
```

should be transformed to:

```
  <datafield tag="866" ind1="" ind2="">
   <subfield code="a">Available from 1997. </subfield>
   ****add the following line with "code" attribute in alphabetical order, after "a" and before "s"****
    <subfield code="i">DEFAULT</subfield>
   <subfield code="s">1000000000001224</subfield>
   <subfield code="t">1000000000000630</subfield>
   <subfield code="x">EBSCOhost Business Source Complete:Full Text</subfield>
   <subfield code="z">10000000value 00125212</subfield>
  </datafield>
```

2) find ALL and ONLY the records titles (it's the content of /collection/record/datafield[\@tag='245']/subfield[\@code='a']) that have:

a) value of "/collection/record/datafield[\@tag='866']/subfield[\@code='x']" equal to "Elsevier SD Freedom Collection:Full Text"
  b) the "/collection/record/datafield[\@tag='866']/subfield[\@code='a']" is totally absent,  OR -if present- is empty.I.E.:

```
 <datafield tag="866" ind1="" ind2="">
   <subfield code="s">1000000000000992</subfield>
   <subfield code="t">1000000000000473</subfield>
   <subfield code="x">Elsevier SD Freedom Collection:Full Text</subfield>
   <subfield code="z">1000000000043233</subfield>
  </datafield>
```

OR

```
<datafield tag="866" ind1="" ind2="">
   <subfield code="a"></subfield>
   <subfield code="s">1000000000000992</subfield>
   <subfield code="t">1000000000000473</subfield>
   <subfield code="x">Elsevier SD Freedom Collection:Full Text</subfield>
   <subfield code="z">1000000000043233</subfield>
  </datafield>
```

thanks a lot for your reply,

fabianope

Comment: What do you want to do with the found records? Also what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

For the first one here is a "naive" solution (ie it loads the entire document in memory, there are ways to avoid this using `twig_roots` if needed):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $coll= "colls.xml";

my $tag_nb= 866;
my $new_subfield= { code => 'i', content => 'DEFAULT' }; 

my $trigger= qq{datafield[\@tag="$tag_nb"]};

my $t= XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { 
                          $trigger => sub{ add_subfied( @_, $new_subfield); }
                          },
                       pretty_print => 'indented',
                     )
               ->parsefile( $coll)
               ->print;

sub add_subfied {
    my( $t, $datafield, $subfield)= @_;
    $datafield->insert_new_elt( first_child => subfield 
                                               => { code => $subfield->{code}, },
                                                  $subfield->{content}
                              );
    $datafield->sort_children_on_att( 'code');
}
```